# How to change directory of a library in a package in ros ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ros

I have installed opencv2.4.9(With No CUDA) by unzip opencv2.4.9.zip in home.
Many successful codes are using this library.
Now I wanna rebuild opencv2.4.9(with CUDA) in another folder.
I don't wanna delete the previous folder because I don't wanna face any problem later on and make my older code can't function.

So, the question is how to change the name of the directory? Seems like we link the package with library in CMake like below:

> include_directories(  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
>
> find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
>
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   cv_bridge   image_transport 
>   OpenCV   roscpp   rospy   std_msgs )

the name of directory is just OpenCV.
So if I got more than one OpenCV library in home, how could I link them separately?

And how to make c++ link to the library if we could change the name?

> ```
> add_executable(xxx src/xxx.cpp)
>
> target_link_libraries(xxx ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
> ```

Comment: Why do you not use OpenCV 3.0? find_package has rules in which order it will look for the library. You can give it hints by defining OpenCV_DIR or adding the preferred OpenCV installation path to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: I use it in Windows, for ROS it is enough for me now.
Thanks for your comment, I get what you means, will try it out soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Libraries can be included and linked with `include_directories()` and `link_directories()`, like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
...
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

include_directories(/path/to/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.1/include)
link_directories(/path/to/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.1/lib)
...

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o op ...
```

So you should not forget the linking in the `CMakeLists.txt` and maybe remove the standard linking to your current OpenCV libs.